# Using Substring to Identify Records and Update Records

Tags: sql, substring

I have Sales Reps that are associated to their Customers by the first three digits of the customer's postal code - this is for US customers only. The Profile_Zip table has two columns Profile_Key representing the Rep and Three_Digits for the first three digits of a postal code.

```
 Profile_Key      Three_Digits
 123456            610
 123456            611
 123456            612
```

Two fields in the Profile table that holds the customer's record are Zip (postal code) and an Association field that holds the Profile_Key of the sales rep.

I need to run a query that updates the Customer's association_key with the rep's profile key from the Profile_Zip table. This is what I've been working with.

```
 update profile set association_key = 
 (select profile_key from profile_zip where three_digits = 
 (Select substring(zip, 1, 3) as ZipPrefix
 From profile group by profile.zip))
```

I know why I get this error, I can't figure out how to make the query work or if Substring is the right/best route to take.

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used
>   as an expression.

Is there another way to do this?
Thanks.

The profile table. 
John Doe is the rep (profile_type =4), Mary is the customer (profile_type = 6). 
John's profile_key is in Mary's Association_key field, that's what binds them. There are of course more fields in the record (address, phone, etc.)

```
 Profile_key    Profile_Type_Key  First_Name   Last_Name   Zip    Association_Key  ...
  123456              4            John            Doe     92112    
  987654              6            Mary            Smith   90210     123456
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you're trying to do there:

```
UPDATE P
SET Association_Key = PZ.Profile_Key
FROM [Profile] P
INNER JOIN Profile_Zip PZ
    ON PZ.Three_Digits = SUBSTRING(P.Zip, 1, 3)
```

The problem is that you're trying to set a scalar value to a result set. In this case you want a result set to update, and then the correct scalar value to use.

Answer (score 0):

The error

`Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

indicates that you're using an `=` when you need to use `IN`. When `=` is used, the system only expects 1 result.

In particular, I'm guessing that:

```
Select substring(zip, 1, 3) as ZipPrefix
From profile
group by profile.zip
```

returns a large number of substrings. Use `IN` outside this subquery.

Comment: no, you're wrong. not in that case. Author, please, publish the structures of all related tables as well as you did for Profile_Zip

Comment: Can you share additional information on your table structure and data?